# Create object from two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create an object from two arrays without using loops in javascript.

example:

```
array1 =  [1,2,3,4,5];
array2 = [A,B,C,D,E];
```

I want from below object

```
obj = {
'1': 'A',
'2': 'B',
'3': 'C',
'4': 'D',
'5': 'E',
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have something against loops?

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: w/o loop https://stackoverflow.com/a/47028434/2012163

Answer (score 7):

```js
var obj = {}

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

array1.forEach(function(value, index) {

  obj[value] = array2[index];

});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `$.each()` to iterate over one of that array and construct the object as per your requirement,

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5],array2 = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
var obj = {};

$.each(array2,function(i,val){
  obj[array1[i]] = val;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ACBeL/)

Comment: `$.each()` is not a loop anymore :)?

Comment: map is essentially a loop too, but whatever :p

Answer (score 1):

An ES6, array reduce solution.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
const resultMap = array1.reduce(
  (accumulator, value, index) => Object.assign(accumulator, {
    [value]: array2[index],
  }), {}
);

console.log(resultMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun created something like this without using any iteration methods.

```
const array1 =  [1,2,3,4,5];
const array2 = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
let combineKeyValueProxy = new Proxy({}, {
    set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
       target[array1[prop]] = value;
       return true
    }
});
const output = Object.assign(combineKeyValueProxy, array2);
console.log(output) // Proxy {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C", 4: "D", 5: "E"}
```